# Openshift - PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, git, openshift

I want to push my php(laravel) project to openshift but I get the following errors from git bash:

[image]

This is what I did:

1. Created a brand new laravel application from openshift's website
2. Cloned the app to my local machine
3. Made some changes
4. Committed
5. Pushed

This is what I get when I attempt to access my url:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the vendor folder was not committed. Check your .gitignore you will notice that the vendor folder is ignored